# Meta page refresh not working for php page?

Tags: php, html, refresh, meta-tags, noscript

i am trying to redirect users without javascript enabled to our help page (help.php), specifically the part that talks about enabling javascript (help.php#nojavascript).

however, my meta refresh is not working! it keeps on refreshing the same page! i tried redirecting to a different page with a `.html` extension instead, and that works, so why doesn't this work?

```
        ...
  </script>
  <!-- if user doesn't have JS enabled, take them to help page -->
  <noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;url=help.php" />
  </noscript>
  </head>
        ...
```

Comment: Can you show the redirect as it looked like when it worked? The file extension should not make a difference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was including a file that redirected the user to home.php =( sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an absolute path:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3;URL=http://www.some.org/some.html">
```

Comment: still a no-go. it works with `.html` pages but not my `help.php` page

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, try taking it out of the NOSCRIPT element. Browsers with scripting enabled are supposed to ignore everything inside NOSCRIPT.

Comment: that's the point; i want users without scripting enabled to be redirected to my help page which teaches them how to enable it

Comment: First make sure the META element works properly as is, then debug the meta-inside-noscript case. Right now, you're not even sure which part misbehaves.